# How to match text string before and after a short hyphen with space

Tags: regex, jscript

My heart will go on - Celine Dion
`My heart will go on  - Celine Dion` 
`My heart will go on    -   Celine Dion`  
My heart will go on -Celine Dion
My heart will go on-    Celine Dion
My heart will go on-Celine Dion

So that is my example String. each of the line must contain a short hyphen. And The space before or after short hyphen can be any number of space even some line have no space before or after short hyphen. I Need to match from every line 2 group of string. `My heart will go on`  and `Celine Dion`. So Which Regular expression can do this?

`/(.*)(\s\-\s)(.*)/gm` this regular expression can match when there is a single space before and after the short hyphen
`^(.*?)[\p{Zs}\t]+-[\p{Zs}\t]+(.*)` This regular expression can match any number of space before and after short hyphen. But problem when there is no space maybe before and maybe after the short hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
(.*?)(?:\s*-\s*)(.*)
```

This matches:

- `(.*?)` all content up to, but not including
- `(?:\s*-\s*)` optional whitespace, a hyphen, and optional whitespace
- `(.*)` all remaining content

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)\s*-\s*(.*)
```

Two captures:

- `(.*?)` - non-greedy capture of zero or more of any character
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `-` - a literal `-`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - capture the rest

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Q1QAv/1)